# How to test Router.push with Jest/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Im still new to unit tests and im struggling to understand how i could test/mock a push from a router,

```
<Tab label="Members" alt="Members" onClick={() => Router.push('/members')}/>
```

the above line is what i need to test but how could i? would i create a fake end point and then test the onClick?

Comment: Could you please show us where `Router` is coming from?

Comment: import Router from 'next/router';

Answer (score 18):

The easiest thing would be to mock the router like this

```
import Router from 'next/router'
jest.mock('next/router', ()=> ({push: jest.fn()}))
```

after simulate the click on `Tab` you can check for the call like this

```
expect(Router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/members')
```

Comment: really helpful tks

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was using `useRouter` from `next/router` and I solved it using the following approach:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useRouter: jest.fn()
}))

describe('XXX', () => {
  it('XXX', () => {
    const mockRouter = {
      push: jest.fn() // the component uses `router.push` only
    }

    (useRouter as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(mockRouter)

    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/hello/world')
  })
})
```

Original answer: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479#issuecomment-626297880

Comment: Thank you! this solution worked for me. It is also flexible because you can set different values for useRouter in each test

Answer (score 9):

I was receiving an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` triny to mock a push of useRouter. This solution worked for me:

1. First mock the useRouter

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

jest.mock("next/router", () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn(),
}));
```

2. And then use like this inside your test block

```
const push = jest.fn();

(useRouter as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({
  push,
}));

userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: 'Move to another route' }));
expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/your-expected-route");
```

Found this answer here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479#issuecomment-778586840