# How to spy on a mock function next.js jest RTL

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock `replace` function which is in `useRouter()` hook from `next/router`
my mocks and tests looks like this:

```js
jest.mock("next/router", () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      route: "/",
      pathname: "",
      locale: "pl",
      replace: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation((obj) => console.log("have been called", obj)),
    };
  },
}));

const routerReplace = jest.spyOn(useRouter(), "replace");
```

```js
      test.only("should redirect when form submitted with success", async () => {
        render(<HomePage {...props} />);

        const routerReplace = jest.spyOn(useRouter(), "replace");
   
        const submitBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
          name: /submit/i,
        });

        userEvent.click(submitBtn);

        //doesn't work
        await waitFor(() => expect(routerReplace).toHaveBeenCalled());

         // I tried also this
         //await waitFor(() =>
         //  expect(useRouter().replace).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
         //);
      });
```

I can see in console that it has been called but the test doesn't pass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test Router.push with Jest/React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986168/how-to-test-router-push-with-jest-react)

Comment: not exactly, one solution is about Router, and another use Typescript, but I figure it out

Comment: Ignoring the fact the second answer uses TypeScript, the concept can be used to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it the way that I spyon `useRouter` , and render page after creating mocks

```js
    test.only("should redirect when form submitted with success", async () => {
        
         const useRouter = jest
          .spyOn(require("next/router"), "useRouter")
          .mockReturnValue({
            ...useRouterProps,
          });
        const routerReplace = jest.spyOn(useRouter(), "replace");
   
        render(<HomePage {...props} />);
        const submitBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
          name: /submit/i,
        });

        userEvent.click(submitBtn);

        await waitFor(() => expect(routerReplace).toHaveBeenCalled());
      });
```

Comment: I'm getting error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...`

Comment: I don't know but this error seems to say, that you use hook somewhere else than function component https://en.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html